# How to prevent 2 players to cross each other in html5 game

Tags: javascript, collision-detection

i would like add collisions between my 2 players (in server side)
[My two players](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k7trq.png)

*Video to show what i want (it's from a game named taming.io) :*
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tGb6PwjHao8

Here is my actual code (every time a player connect, it create a new Player class) :

```
class Player {
    static list = new Set()
    constructor(id) {
        Player.list[id] = this
        this.id = id;
        this.x = 250;
        this.y = 250;
        this.pressingUp = false;
        this.pressingLeft = false;
        this.pressingDown = false;
        this.pressingRight = false;
        this.moveSpeed = 5;
        this.moveAngle = 45;
        this.radians = this.moveAngle * Math.PI / 180;
        this.vx = Math.cos(this.radians) * this.moveSpeed;
        this.vy = Math.sin(this.radians) * this.moveSpeed;
    }


    //Apply new positions
    update() {

        //Players collisions
        for (const i in Player.list) {

            const player = Player.list[i];

            const calcDistance = Math.hypot(player.x - this.x, player.y - this.y)

            if (calcDistance <= 200 && player != this) {
                //What should i put ?
            }
        }

        //Player moves
        if (this.pressingUp === true) {
            this.y -= this.vy;
        }
        else if (this.pressingDown === true) {
            this.y += this.vy;
        }
        if (this.pressingRight === true) {
            this.x += this.vx;
        }
        else if (this.pressingLeft === true) {
            this.x -= this.vx;
        }   
    }
}
```

So i'm calculating distance between players with calcDistance const, if calcDistance = 200 (players radius hitbox = 100, so player1 radius hitbox + player2 radius hitbox = 200), it should do something, but i dont know what

Can you please help me ?

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: I tried to inverse the movespeed if calcdistance = 200, but the player start shaking and i want it stay normal, just cant pass

Comment: One thing I am unable to determine is if this is circular detection or rectangle. Your constructor lacks a width/height and also lacks a radius. Are you trying to implement rectangle collision or circle? The formula will be different.

Comment: It's circular with a radius of 100,  so if the distance between the two player is 200 (player1 hitbox radius + player2 hitbox radius) it should do something

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the distance between the center of the circles using `Math.hypot()` like you have. See if that distance is less than the radii of the two circles. Once you have that you can set the x,y and optionally the vx,vy of the player.

The x will be set to `obj2.x` plus the two radii combined multiplied by the distance of each x and y value divided by the total distance. More triangle math...

Here's an example

```js
let canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
canvas.width = 500;
canvas.height = 500;

class Circle {
  constructor(x, y, c) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.color = c;
    this.r = 30;
    this.vx = 0;
    this.vy = 0;
    this.speed = 0.5;
  }
  draw() {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.fillStyle = this.color;
    ctx.arc(this.x, this.y, this.r, 0, Math.PI*2);
    ctx.fill();

  }
  update() {
    if (controller.left) {
      this.vx -= this.speed;
    }
    if (controller.up) {
      this.vy -= this.speed;
    }
    if (controller.right) {
      this.vx +=  this.speed;
    }
    if (controller.down) {
      this.vy += this.speed
    }
    
    this.x += this.vx;
    this.y += this.vy;
    this.vx *= 0.9;
    this.vy *= 0.9;
  }
}

class Controller {
  constructor() {
    this.up = false;
    this.right = false;
    this.down = false;
    this.left = false;

    let keyEvent = (e) => {
      if (e.code == "ArrowUp") {
        this.up = e.type == "keydown";
      }
      if (e.code == "ArrowRight") {
        this.right = e.type == "keydown";
      }
      if (e.code == "ArrowLeft") {
        this.left = e.type == "keydown";
      }
      if (e.code == "ArrowDown") {
        this.down = e.type == "keydown";
      }
    };
    addEventListener("keydown", keyEvent);
    addEventListener("keyup", keyEvent);
  }
}

let player = new Circle(25, 25, 'blue');
let obstacle = new Circle(canvas.width/2, 150, 'red');
let controller = new Controller();

function collisionDetection(obj1, obj2) {
  if (Math.hypot(obj1.x - obj2.x, obj1.y - obj2.y) <= obj1.r + obj2.r) {
      collisionResponse(obj1, obj2)
  }
  
}

function collisionResponse(obj1, obj2) {
  let dx = obj1.x - obj2.x;
  let dy = obj1.y - obj2.y;
  let dist = (Math.hypot(obj1.x - obj2.x, obj1.y - obj2.y)) || 1;
  let radii = obj1.r + obj2.r;
  let x = dx / dist;
  let y = dy / dist;
  
  obj1.x = obj2.x + radii * x;
  obj1.y = obj2.y + radii * y;
  obj1.vx = 0; //optional
  obj1.vy = 0; //optional
}

function animate() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  collisionDetection(player, obstacle)
  player.update();
  player.draw();  
  obstacle.draw();
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
}
animate();
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Setting the vx and vy are optional and will prevent any overlap from occurring. You can also choose to not set them to 0 and you will have some overlap but the circle will seem to slide off of eachother smoother.